# Sudoku Solver using backtrack method in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Sudoku solver in java but it is not working as expected and I cannot figure out why. I have added the code below in comments so hopefully someone can figure out the problem. For some reason, it halts in the middle. I suspect it is an infinite loop that has passed through with no error but I cannot identify it. There is more code but it is not necessary since it is just printing the board and filling the board.

```
private static int row2 = 0;
private static int col2 = 0;
private static boolean isEnd = false;

public static void backTrack(String[][] puzzle) { 
    int[][] puzzle2 = new int[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 9; i2++) {
            puzzle2[i][i2] = Integer.parseInt(puzzle[i][i2]); //Takes the String puzzle and turns it into integers and adds it to puzzle2
        }
    }
    int[][] puzzle3 = new int[9][9];
    puzzle3 = puzzle2; //Initiates puzzle3 so that I can have a fresh copy that I can use to reference to later
    while (isEnd == false) { //isEnd is defined in nextCell and determines whether or not the solution has been found or not
        if (puzzle3[row2][col2] != 0) {
            nextCell(); //if the cell was originally already set (that is why I use puzzle3), then it should just go to the next cell
        } else if (puzzle3[row2][col2] == 0) { //0 being empty. So if the cell was not originally filled
            while (puzzle2[row2][col2] <= 9) {
                puzzle2[row2][col2] = puzzle2[row2][col2] + 1; //Add 1 to the current number in the cell
                if (puzzle2[row2][col2] == 10) { //If it is 10, since it can, then it means that none of the numbers have worked in that cell, so it should go back a cell
                    puzzle2[row2][col2] = 0;//Sets it to 0 before going back one cell
                    backCell(); //method to go back a cell
                    while(true){
                        if(puzzle3[row2][col2]!=0){
                            backCell(); //if the cell it goes back onto was originally set, then it should keep going back until it finds one that it can change
                        }
                        else{
                            break; //breaks out of the infinite while loop , so that it can carry on checking solutions from the cell it just went onto. 
                        }
                    }
                    break; //breaks out of the second while loop
                }
                if (isValid(row2, col2, puzzle2[row2][col2], puzzle2)) {
                    nextCell(); //if the new number is valid, then it should go to the next cell and try out solutions from there
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printBoard2(puzzle2); // method to print the board(which is meant to be solved at this point
}
public static void backCell() {
    col2--; 
    if (col2 < 0) { 
        col2 = 8;
        row2--;
    }
    if (row2 < 0) {
        row2 = 0;
        col2 = 0;
    }
}

public static void nextCell() {
    col2++;
    if (col2 > 8) {
        col2 = 0;
        row2++;
    }
    if (row2 > 8) {
        isEnd = true; //if it manages to reach the end of the puzzle, it can be assumed that the solution has been found
    }
}
 public static boolean isValid(int row, int col, int value, int[][]puzzle) {     
    boolean check = true;
    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 9; i3++) {
        if (i3 != col) {
            if (puzzle[row][i3] == (value)) {
                check = false;
                break;

            }//checks whether the values are repeated in the same row
        }

    }
    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 9; i3++) {
        if (i3 != row) {
            if (puzzle[i3][col] == (value)) {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }//checks whether the values are repeated in the same column

    }

    int initRow = 0;
    int initCol = 0;
    if (row <= 2) {
        initRow = 0;
    } else if (row <= 5 && row > 2) {
        initRow = 3;
    } else if (row <= 8 && row > 5) {
        initRow = 6;
    }
    if (col <= 2) {
        initCol = 0;
    } else if (col <= 5 && col > 2) {
        initCol = 3;
    } else if (col <= 8 && col > 5) {
        initCol = 6;
    }//finds the top left coordinates of the box that it is in

    if (puzzle[initRow][initCol] == value
            && (initRow != row || initCol != col)) {
        check = false; //checks whether the value is in the box. The second part of each if statement checks whether the coordinates are the same as the value entered(since the value is already added before validation)
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 1][initCol] == value
            && ((initRow + 1) != row || initCol != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 2][initCol] == value
            && ((initRow + 2) != row || initCol != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow][initCol + 1] == value
            && (initRow != row || (initCol + 1) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow][initCol + 2] == value
            && (initRow != row || (initCol + 2) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 1][initCol + 1] == value
            && ((initRow + 1) != row || (initCol + 1) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 2][initCol + 1] == value
            && ((initRow + 2) != row || (initCol + 1) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 1][initCol + 2] == value
            && ((initRow + 1) != row || (initCol + 2) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }
    if (puzzle[initRow + 2][initCol + 2] == value
            && ((initRow + 2) != row || (initCol + 2) != col)) {
        check = false;
    }

    if (check == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
public static void main(String[]args){
    String[][] puzzle = new String[9][9];
    fillBoard(puzzle);
    backTrack(puzzle);
}
```

Comment: There's no fillBoard function. try to debug and show what function it's stuck

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't "make a copy" of your array

```
puzzle3 = puzzle2
```

You can initialize puzzle3 in the same time as puzzle2:

```
int[][] puzzle2 = new int[9][9];
    int[][] puzzle3 = new int[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 9; i2++) {
            int v = Integer.parseInt(puzzle[i][i2]);
            puzzle2[i][i2] = v; //Takes the String puzzle and turns it into integers and adds it to puzzle2
            puzzle3[i][i2] = v;
        }
    }
```